# ITERROWS: Print Row Value Only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When we use:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # prints tuple (column, value)
    print(row)

    # prints column name (left side)
    print (row.index)
```

How do we print just the value (the right side of the tuple?)

Comment: @glibdud yes. Thanks for reminding me to edit it

Comment: Please add tags to the tags section, not the title. Edited this one for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # prints tuple (column, value)
    print(row.values)

    # prints column name (left side)
    print (row.index.values)
```